# Creating pedestrians at random after every simulation in a given area

Tags: anylogic

I would like to know if it is possible to create a random distribution of pedestrians at a given area each time I begin my simulation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwS67.jpg)

Comment: Please specify your requirements a bit more. What exactly do you mean by "random distributuon"? Do you only want a variable number of pedestrians per area, or should it also be different pedestrian types or have different pedestrian properties? Should all of the pedestrains in the model be in one population or do you need them in several populations?

Comment: You could just create a pedestrian population, set the nr. of agents created property to a probabilistic value from a random distribution and set the location the space markup area where you want them to appear.

Comment: Actually I would like pedestrians to be distributed around a given area at random and appear at areas without having to come from an entrance. For example a floor with 75 occupants. Certain areas such as the offices will have fixed number of people, but the student lounge could have 20-30 students after every simulation run. Can this be done through the pedestrian library or must I use the create pedestrian population option?

Comment: You are talking about 2 different topics here. One is the creation of the pedestrians, for this just use a population or a source. The other topic is the initial location, which you can set during the creation (in the properties of the source, or in the properties of the population). You can also create them at any or unspecified location and then during startup just use Pedestrian.jumpTo() command to put them where they should be. To define an area you can use the polygonal area markup. If you set such an area as location, Peds will be distributed there randomly, or according to attractors.

Comment: Oh I see. I tried using the create pedestrian by population method but was unable to make them follow my project on fire evacuation. They don't move and remain stationary at the places I set them to. 
I am more comfortable using the pedSource from pedestrian library and would like to know if I can make my pedestrians go around different areas from a single pedSource?

Comment: For example: From one pedSource of 100, I would like 30 of them to fill up the offices using attractors, as it is easy to have them exactly where I want them to be and the rest to appear randomly at two different student areas.
My apologies for not making things very clear.

Comment: As said before you have several options to do so: Option 1) Specify the initial location right in the Source. You can do so individually for each agent by putting a function there that returns one of the areas, for example dependant of an agent id. Option 2) you can also in the OnExit code of the source use a jumpTo() command to place each one where it should be, before it goes into your normal process flow for the evacuation.

Comment: You do need two kind of things: A data structure where you hold the information which agent should be where at start. Can be a table in the internal database,  information stored in a Collection, or read from a file, etc. And second, a function that converts/parses this stored information (I guess stored as a name of the area as a String) into actual area areas (eg. INode).

Comment: Understood. I edited my question with an image of my current problem. So does that mean I can follow either of the options to solve this?

Comment: Sure. Are the moveTo blocks you have in your images already the evacuation or still the "filling the rooms" ? Is my answer below helping you?

Comment: It's the "filling rooms". I tried making them as a collection using the code you provided with pedestrians.But ended up with one error at pedWait for "Area", is there another code that is required here?

Comment: Do you get the error "cannot convert from INode to AreaNode" ? Seems like the ped library needs AreaNodes instead INode. Try changing the type of the Collection list to that.

Comment: I modified my answer to use PedLibrary and Areas instead of ProcessModellingLibrary and Nodes.

Comment: And also added a link to my example model.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Collection named allLocations of type AreaNode that contains all of your possible initialisation areas:

[image: area collection]

Use a process flow like the following with a PedSource:

[image: canvas]

Set the *Area* property in the *PedSource* to the following:

```java
allLocations.get(uniform_discr(0, allLocations.size()-1))
```

This code randomly assigns one of the areas in the list to each agent as a start. You can modify this to fit your needs, with other distributions for example.

You can now see how Agents pop up randomly at the different locations:

[image: model]

The example model can be run and downloaded [here](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/2ad6b6d2-221b-40f5-9ad1-aef689a8962f?mode=SETTINGS).

Comment: Sorry, without seeing the exact process flow and a good explanation what is happening including code, it's not possible to give advice on what might cause this. Consider posting another separate question where you exactly describe the situation in which the agents are not moving as expected.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to add on something.

Comment: One last thing. You did mention if areas have attractors I can make pedestrians fill them up automatically. I tried using 10 attractors for an area but more pedestrians fill that particular area. Is there a way to fill other areas without filling the one with attractors?

Comment: Thats something you have to control yourself with the code where you assign an initial location.Instead of the one line 'allLocations.get(uniform_discr(0, allLocations.size()-1))' you can write a more complex function that checks if a maximum for a certain area has been reached or other requirements.

Comment: I'm so sorry sir but can you show me an example of how I can write that code? Or at least a way for the pedestrians to appear at the exact attractor only?

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt belong to this question anymore. Please, for your next questions: Give more details in your question. Your question has 2 lines, the answer one page, it should be the other way round. State exactly what you want to achieve and why and all your restrictions and assumptions. Add images from the start of your current state, add code you use, explain how your model works so far. Focus on one small topic per question.

Comment: And yes, I noticed that the attractors are not automatically used, I described that incorrectly. You'll have to find out on how to put the pedestrians on attractors. Maybe you do have to include a pedWait block again, which allows for attractor setting, not sure.

Comment: Yes, so sorry for the trouble. I'll make things more clearer the next time I post a question.